# Group by data by month with selected fields not to be included in group by class

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to group by the data by the only `month` but I need the `no_inv` and `date_inv` columns to be selected too.

Mysql query :

```
SELECT no_inv, date_inv, SUM(total_unpaid) AS unpaid, SUM(total_paid) AS paid
FROM invoice
GROUP BY MONTH(date_inv)
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum! You could look at the ANY_VALUE function - similar to, but not as good as PostgreSQL's DISTINCT ON functionality. You will essentially select a random no_inv and a random date_inv **together with** the SUMs that you desiire but month. Why is one random invoice number and/or date relevant to the SUMs over a month - these may occur at the first  of the month (more likely to be paid) or the end ? Any why have a total_unpaid and a total_unpaid field?Just have an invoice_is_paid BOOLEAN field...? Provide the structure of your invoice table and there may be an alternative.

Comment: Always include your version of MySQL - there's a lot of new functionality in recent releases!

Comment: Finally, SELECT COUNT(total_paid) and COUNT(total_unpaid) might be better? Also, is total_paid an amount/invoice? Too many variables to tell so far - please include explanations of what fields are for with your table structure!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense (even a as concept) to be able to `SELECT` non-aggregated fields that aren't part of the `GROUP BY` clause, because when you group on a field, you're literally condensing **many** rows into **one** row for each unique value of that field you're grouping on. So it wouldn't be possible to display a non-grouped (and non-aggregated) field because that field may have multiple different values within the grouping of the field in the `GROUP BY` clause, so it would not be possible to show two different values of the non-grouped field in the same row for the grouped field.

That being said, I think I understand the reasoning behind your question, which I assume is you're more so looking for a way to aggregate across a grouping and display that aggregation with the other non-grouped fields. This **is possible** to accomplish with [**window functions**](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) via the [`OVER`](https://learnsql.com/blog/over-clause-mysql/) and [`PARTITION BY`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-partition-by-clause/) clause like this:

```
SELECT no_inv, date_inv, SUM(total_unpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(date_inv)) AS unpaid, 
    SUM(total_paid) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(date_inv)) AS paid
FROM invoice
LIMIT 3
```

Please note the `OVER()` clause (and  **window functions**) was introduced in MySQL 8.0.